# Use multi select parameter values in SSRS grouping expression

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

We have a multi value parameter "Group BY" in `ssrs` report, it has values as available field names of the data set, I want to pass the values selected to the grouping expression what could be the way to achieve this.

when I `pass "=Fields!Category.Value &","& Fields!ProductName.Value"` it works However, when I pass the parameter values its not working for me.

I tried below VB code and passed =code.SamTest(Parameters!GroupBY) as grouping expression it doesn't work.

```
Public Function SamTest(ByVal parm as Parameter) as string
   Dim s as String 

      For i as integer = 0 to parm.Count-1
          s &= "Fields!"&Cstr(parm.value(i)) &".Value & " &""","" & " 
      Next
 ' Remove the trailing comma
    If Len(s) > 0 Then
        s = Left(s, Len(s) - 9)
    End If
  Return s
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that when you manually type in your expression it gets evaluated as the concatenated value of the Category and ProductName field, the comma between them is doing nothing.  It's the equivalent to doing this in a SQL query

```
SELECT Category, ProductName, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    FROM myTable 
    GROUP BY CONCAT(Category, ', ', ProductName)
```

When you try to build an expression, all you are doing is grouping by the literal string that your code is producing, basically it's saying

```
GROUP BY "Fields!Category.Value, Fields!ProductName.Value"
```

so it's grouping by the literal string.

I don't think you can build an expression to be evaluated as you intend.

You could do this in your dataset query but it would mean using dynamic sql (always a bit dodgy) and you would have to fix the number of columns returned from your query (even if some return null values) as SSRS expects the dataset query to always return the same number of columns with the same data type.

If you need more help on that approach, ask a new question.